# Ignore routes in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need help with converting this to vb.net...

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*robotstxt}", new {robotstxt=@"(.*/)?robots.txt(/.*)?"});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", New With {.allaspx = ".*\.aspx(/.*)?"})
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*robotstxt}", New With {.robotstxt = "(.*/)?robots.txt(/.*)?"})
```

Comment: Thanks :) The code throws no error, but the route is not ignored. I will mark your answer as correct and investigate why routes are not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import `System.Web.Mvc`

this is what I used in a VB.NET ASP.net Web-Forms app (with mvc5)

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Public Module RouteConfig
    Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

        ' keep default.aspx for empty url
        routes.IgnoreRoute("")

        routes.MapRoute(
            name:="Default",
            url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        )
    End Sub
End Module
```